# binary classification label names

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

If I have a binary classification problem that I want to build a model from using sklearn or matlab. Should the label files contain 0 and 1 or it can instead contain the name for classes for example "R" (for rainy) and "S"(for sunny)? should I convert it to 0 and 1?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is appropriate here, at least in it's current form. To answer it as a comment though, it depends. Some packages will let you enter the labels as strings and do some type of conversion "on the inside", but what's most common is you transform your labels to some binary case (i.e {0,1}), in sklearn for example, you're probably better off transforming the labels to the binary numerical case.

Comment: I tried both it did not change but as you said I think it's better to convert to 0 and 1

Comment: @atomsmasher, I dont agree that it would be better with converting. Scikit-learn will automatically handle (convert) them. Just pass them as strings if you have strings. Dont do anything. It should (and will) not change the results.

Comment: @Vivek: what about multi classification do you think that also gives the same result without label encoding?

Comment: As I said, scikit itself will do the encoding internally, so you dont need to. Its for all binary as well as multiclass. In any other case, scikit will give the appropriate error so dont worry about wrong training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of label should have no influence on the model. Regardless of whether you use `0` and `1` or `R` and `S` you should get the same exact results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Do you also think this should be the same for multi classification or for that we need the label encoder for sklearn?

Comment: @Sahar It should be the same